# How to derive an option price for an asset with these dynamics?

Tags: options, stochastic-calculus

Assuming my underline asset price follows the process:

$$d\ln (F_{t,T})=-(1/2)\sigma ^2e^{-2\lambda(T-t)}dt+\sigma e^{-\lambda(T-t)}dB_t $$

How should I derive an option price formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0 < T_0\le T$, consider the option with payoff, at the option maturity $T_0$, of the form
\begin{align*}
\max(F_{T_0, T}-K, \, 0).\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{align*}
F_{T_0, T} &= F_{0, T}\exp\left(-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\int_0^{T_0} e^{-2\lambda (T-t)} dt+\sigma \int_0^{T_0}e^{-\lambda (T-t)} dB_t\right).
\end{align*}
Let
\begin{align*}
\hat{\sigma}^2 &= \frac{\sigma^2}{T_0}\int_0^{T_0} e^{-2\lambda (T-t)} dt\\
&=\frac{e^{-2\lambda T}\sigma^2}{2\lambda T_0}\left(e^{2\lambda T_0} -1\right).
\end{align*}
Then, in distribution,
\begin{align*}
F_{T_0, T} = F_{0, T}\exp\left(-\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{2} T_0 + \hat{\sigma} \sqrt{T_0} Z\right),
\end{align*}
where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. The value of Payoff $(1)$ is now given by
\begin{align*}
e^{-r T_0}\Big[F_{0, T}\Phi(d_1) - K\Phi(d_2) \Big],
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= \frac{\ln \frac{F_{0, T}}{K} + \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{2} T_0}{\hat{\sigma} \sqrt{T_0}},\\
d_2 &= d_1 - \hat{\sigma} \sqrt{T_0},
\end{align*}
and $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable.

Comment: That's pretty cool. I'm learning the fundamentals of option pricing, and I'll change my underline process to derive this by myself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @snowave: To deriive it by yourself is a good learning process.

Comment: is the option delta = N(d1)? I assume it is.

Comment: @snowave: The delta with respect to $F_{0, T}$ is $e^{-rT_0} \Phi(d_1)$.

Comment: hi，what about if lnF is a two factor model？can i use the same method？

Comment: @snowave: I do not know the specific format of the two factor model. Basically, you can proceed similarly.