# Option price derivation with these dynamics

Tags: stochastic-calculus

If my underlying follows a dynamics of the form 
\begin{align*}
dF(t,T)/F(t,T)=\sigma_1(t,T)dW_1(t)+\sigma_2(t,T)dW_2(t),
\end{align*}
where $\sigma_1(t,T)=h_1e^{-\lambda(T-t)}+h_0$, and $\sigma_2(t,T)=h_2e^{-\lambda(T-t)}$. How to derive an option price?

Comment: Are $W_1$ and $W_2$ correlated or independent?

Comment: they are independent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proceed similarly to [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27652/how-to-derive-an-option-price-for-an-asset-with-these-dynamics.).

For $0 < T_0\le T$, consider the option with payoff, at the option maturity $T_0$, of the form
\begin{align*}
\max(F_{T_0, T}-K, \, 0).\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{align*}
F_{T_0, T} &= F_{0, T}\exp\Bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{T_0} \left[\left(h_1e^{-\lambda (T-t)}+h_0\right)^2 + h_2^2e^{-2\lambda (T-t)} \right] dt\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad +\int_0^{T_0}\left[\left(h_1e^{-\lambda (T-t)}+h_0\right)dW_t^1 + h_2e^{-\lambda (T-t)}dW_t^2\right]\Bigg).
\end{align*}
Let
\begin{align*}
\hat{\sigma}^2 &= \frac{1}{T_0}\int_0^{T_0} \left[\left(h_1e^{-\lambda (T-t)}+h_0\right)^2 + h_2^2e^{-2\lambda (T-t)} \right] dt\\
&=\frac{e^{-2\lambda T}(h_1^2+h_2^2)}{2\lambda T_0}\left(e^{2\lambda T_0} -1\right)+\frac{2e^{-\lambda T}h_0h_1}{\lambda T_0}\left(e^{\lambda T_0} -1\right) + h_0^2.
\end{align*}
Then, in distribution,
\begin{align*}
F_{T_0, T} = F_{0, T}\exp\left(-\frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{2} T_0 + \hat{\sigma} \sqrt{T_0} Z\right),
\end{align*}
where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. The value of Payoff $(1)$ is now given by
\begin{align*}
e^{-r T_0}\Big[F_{0, T}\Phi(d_1) - K\Phi(d_2) \Big],
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= \frac{\ln \frac{F_{0, T}}{K} + \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{2} T_0}{\hat{\sigma} \sqrt{T_0}},\\
d_2 &= d_1 - \hat{\sigma} \sqrt{T_0},
\end{align*}
and $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable.